# Generating code -- is there an easy way to get a proper string representation of nullable type?

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-generation

So I'm building an application that is going to do a ton of code generation with both C# and VB output (depending on project settings).

I've got a CodeTemplateEngine, with two derived classes VBTemplateEngine and CSharpTemplateEngine. This question regards creating the property signatures based on columns in a database table. Using the IDataReader's GetSchemaTable method I gather the CLR type of the column, such as "System.Int32", and whether it IsNullable. However, I'd like to keep the code simple, and instead of having a property that looks like:

```
    public System.Int32? SomeIntegerColumn { get; set; }
```

or

```
    public Nullable<System.Int32> SomeIntegerColumn { get; set; },
```

where the property type would be resolved with this function (from my VBTemplateEngine),

```
    public override string ResolveCLRType(bool? isNullable, string runtimeType)
    {
        Type type = TypeUtils.ResolveType(runtimeType);
        if (isNullable.HasValue && isNullable.Value == true && type.IsValueType)
        {
            return "System.Nullable(Of " + type.FullName + ")";
            // or, for example...
            return type.FullName + "?";
        }
        else
        {
            return type.FullName;
        }
    },
```

I would like to generate a simpler property. I hate the idea of building a Type string from nothing, and I would rather have something like:

```
    public int? SomeIntegerColumn { get; set; }
```

Is there anything built-in anywhere, such as in the VBCodeProvider or CSharpCodeProvider classes that would somehow take care of this for me?

Or is there a way to get a type alias of `int?` from a type string like `System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

[Found something](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2010/02/blog-post.html) that would do, but I'm still wary of that type of mapping of Type full names to their aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using CodeDom's support for generic types and the GetTypeOutput method:

```
CodeTypeReference ctr;
if (/* you want to output this as nullable */)
{
  ctr = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Nullable<>));
  ctr.TypeArguments.Add(new CodeTypeReference(typeName));
}
else
{
  ctr = new CodeTypeReference(typeName);
}
string typeName = codeDomProvider.GetTypeOutput(ctr);
```

This will respect language-specific type keywords such as C# `int` or VB `Integer`, though it will still give you `System.Nullable<int>` rather than `int?`.

Comment: This will get me about half-way there, which is better than what I started with. I'll try it out tonight and let you know my thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Although this method may not be ideal for everyone, it suits me and answers my questions of "is there another way." Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. `System.Int32` has the C# alias `int`, which you prefer.
2. `System.Nullable` can be indicated using a `?` symbol in C#, which you prefer.

There are no methods included with the .NET Framework to take these into account when converting the type name to a string. You are going to have to roll your own.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: <That's what I figured.> I considered writing some code, but from your post, it looks like you've mostly got it figured out already.

Comment: The CodeDomProvider.GetTypeOutput method takes account of #1.  You're right about #2 though as far as I know.