# Get C#-style type reference from CLR-style type full name

Tags: c#, reflection, types, decompiling, pretty-print

Given a .NET type object found through reflection, is it possible to pretty print or decompile this type as a C# declaration, taking into account C# type aliases, etc.?

For example,

```
Int32 -> int
String -> string   
Nullable<Int32> -> int?
List<au.net.ExampleObject> -> List<ExampleObject>
```

I want to be able to print out methods close to what was originally written in the source.

If there isn't anything in the .NET framework, is there a third-party library?  I might possibly have a look at [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459577/generating-code-is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-a-proper-string-representation-of/2459614#2459614) answer.

**Example:**

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

var typeRef = new CodeTypeReference("System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]");
string typeOutput = provider.GetTypeOutput(typeRef); // "System.Nullable<int>"
```

It will help you with `int` and `string`-like things, as well as generics, however you'll have to work out `Nullable<T> -> T?` and `using`s yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are compiled to what they are an alias for. You will never know if it was `string` or `String` in the source and frankly I can't see why it would matter.

Comment: I realise this, I was trying to suggest I would prefer the alias if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[There are only 15 aliases (+Nullable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c/215422#215422). Just use string.Replace on these.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for type declarations in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448800/given-a-type-instance-how-to-get-generic-type-name-in-c) .
You can extend it to support type aliases easily.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I considered looking at the source of a c# decompiler.  Actually, Jon Skeet has mentioned CSharpCodeProvider in another question.