# Get MethodInfo Signature

Tags: c#, string, reflection, signature, methodinfo

Say you have a MethodInfo relating to the method myMethod:

```
void myMethod(int param1, int param2) { }
```

and you want to create a string that represents the method's signature:

```
string myString = "myMethod (int, int)";
```

Looping through the MethodInfo parameters, I was able to achieve these results by calling the parameter types' ToString methods:

```
"myMethod (System.Int32, System.Int32)"
```

How can I improve on this and produce the results shown above?

Comment: The case of `myMethod` should not have changed -- are you only referring to the `Sysetm.Int32` vs. `int` part?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo which has now been fixed. Yes, my problem is with displaying a type's name the way it is declared. I'm wondering if there is a better solution than hard-coding a string for each type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked before, and it can done through the CodeDom api. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6263536/517852) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459614/517852). Note that those keywords (int, bool, etc.) are language specific, so if you are outputting this for a general .NET consumer the framework type names are usually preferred.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is nothing built-in that will convert the *real* type name of a primitive (`System.Int32`) to the built-in alias (`int`).  Since there is only a very small number of these aliases, it's not too difficult to write your own method:

```
public static string GetTypeName(Type type) 
{
    if (type == typeof(int))  // Or "type == typeof(System.Int32)" -- same either way
        return "int";
    else if (type == typeof(long))
        return "long";
    ...
    else
        return type.Name;     // Or "type.FullName" -- not sure if you want the namespace
}
```

That being said, if the user actually *did* type in `System.Int32` rather than `int` (which of course would be perfectly legal) this technique would still print out "int".  There's not a whole lot you can do about that because the `System.Type` is the same either way -- so there's no way for you to find out which variant the user actually typed.

Comment: IIRC there is something in CodeDom that can do this.